# Argument in `predict.lm` function

Tags: r, arguments, prediction

The head of the `predict.lm` function is

```
predict.lm <- function (object, newdata, se.fit = FALSE, scale = NULL, df = Inf,
                        interval = c("none", "confidence", "prediction"), level = 0.95,
                        type = c("response", "terms"), terms = NULL, na.action = na.pass,
                        pred.var = res.var/weights, weights = 1, ...)
```

I'm having some trouble understanding how the argument `pred.var = res.var/weights` is evaluated.

I know that it stands for the variance of the residues, but it is passed as a variable as oposed to a character string where it could later be read and translated.

The help for this function is not explicit about this issue, which I think could be related to the way R actually works and not so much with this particular function.

Some how, the argument `pred.var` will default to the variance of the residues - `sd(fit$residuals)^2` - but I cannot see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here is R's mechanism of lazy evaluation for function arguments. Take a look at a simplified example:

```
lazy_arg <- function(x, y = z) {
    z <- sum(x * x)
    x / y
}
lazy_arg(1:5, y = 10)
#[1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
lazy_arg(1:5)
#[1] 0.01818182 0.03636364 0.05454545 0.07272727 0.09090909
```

The second call obviously won't work in languages that evaluate arguments immediately after the call takes place. Instead, R just keeps the "recipe" `y = z` and evaluates it only when `y` is actually used. Of course, when I write such function I have to ensure that `z` is properly defined before I use `y`, otherwise I provide a great opportunity to shoot myself in the leg:

```
bad_arg <- function(x, y = z) {
    if (runif(1) > 0.5) z <- 1
    x / y
}

set.seed(112)
z <- 1e5
bad_arg(1:5)
#[1] 1e-05 2e-05 3e-05 4e-05 5e-05
bad_arg(1:5)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

If you're wondering why that happened, that's how R's [variable lookup](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/) works (in short, that's the unintended clash with the top-level environment). So the flexibility comes at a price here.

However, in the case of `predict.lm` that's quite convenient, because it provides a reasonable default value on the spot, and it is actually computed much later and depends on other arguments.

For further details and possibilities see "Lazy evaluation" subsection of Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R": http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

Comment: The article mencioned by tonytonov on how R's variable lookup works is a must read.